# how does =IF(ISBLANK(PasteCell),"",CopyCell) work

Tags: excel, vba

I am studying from my VBA Excel book command by command. I understand if this is applied to specific cells, BUT how can I make this work if I am incrementing through column(B) on ws specX and finding a value in column(D) ws specY and checking if Column(E) ws specX offset cell is blank?  This is my looping code (which works well, but i don't want to write over the found offset cell that has Data on ws specX) My code writes over all cells in ws specX. Which is not what I want. I am thinking I need some variables and maybe putting "isblank" in each find copy line

```
Option explicit

Sub Rework31Dec20231200b()
    'raw data cloumns
    'BBBBBBBBBB

    ' Define variables
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim specX As Worksheet: Set specX = wb.Sheets("specX")
    Dim specY As Worksheet: Set specY = wb.Sheets("specY")
    Dim rngX As Range
    Dim rngY As Range
    Dim strStart As String: strStart = "START"
        
    Set rngX = specX.Cells.Find(strStart) ' Find the "start" cell in specX
       
    Do While Not rngX Is Nothing   ' Loop until stops, 
        
        
        If rngX.Offset(1, 1).Value = "STOP_4" Then Exit Do ' Loop until "STOP_4"

        rngX.Offset(1, 1).Copy 'incremnt row

        specY.Range("b1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste to specY
        
        Set rngY = specY.Range("b2:b2600").Find(specY.Range("b1").Value) 'find specY "b1"
        
        If Not rngY Is Nothing Then ' Neg logic test

            'each Cost
            rngY.Offset(0, 8).Copy  'copy specY Data
            rngX.Offset(1, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste specY data to specX
            
            ' case cost
            rngY.Offset(0, 7).Copy  'copy specY Data
            rngX.Offset(1, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste specY data to specX
            
            ' SRP
            rngY.Offset(0, 10).Copy  'copy specY Data
            rngX.Offset(1, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste specY data to specX
            
            '% markup
            rngY.Offset(0, 9).Copy  'copy specY Data
            rngX.Offset(1, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste specY data to specX
        
        
             'case size
           rngY.Offset(0, 5).Copy  'copy Ynew Data
           rngX.Offset(1, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste Ynew data to Ynew
        
            Range("a1").Clear
        
        End If
        
        
        Set rngX = rngX.Offset(1, 0) ' back to specX next row
    
    Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have the right idea but your question title uses the worksheet formula `IF` instead of the VBA `If` statement. The VBA equivalent of the `ISBLANK` formula is `IsEmpty`.

Here is how you would do it in VBA, for example the each Cost line. You would have to repeat the same approach for the other cells that you want to check for blanks.

```
'each Cost
If IsEmpty(rngX.Offset(1, 6)) Then
    rngY.Offset(0, 8).Copy  'copy specY Data
    rngX.Offset(1, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste specY data to specX
End If
```

Or if you want to use a variable:

```
'each Cost
Dim PasteCell As Range
Set PasteCell = rngX.Offset(1, 6)
If IsEmpty(PasteCell) Then
    rngY.Offset(0, 8).Copy  'copy specY Data
    rngX.Offset(1, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste specY data to specX
End If
```

Comment: Went back to book found where I went wrong. appreciate it kevin